# Can I define constants based on the runtime identifier in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, interop, runtime-identifier

I have a .NET Core Console application.  My goal here is to be able to conditionally `DLLImport` a function and call it, but only on Windows runtimes.

I thought maybe if I could access the runtime identifier in the `csproj` file, I could conditionally define a constant for that runtime, then in my c# I could surround the DLLImport and calls in `#if`/`#endif` blocks.

Is it possible to set compilation constants within a `csproj` based on the runtime the project is being built for?  This is specifically for an SDK-style Project format (that starts with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`) that is targeting .NET Core.

Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557327/dot-net-core-build-platform-os-specific-code-or-class-files) gets close, but is for `project.json` style projects.

Alternately, is there a better approach to accomplish my goal?

Comment: you can define compiler constants in .csproj depending on some conditions. For example:

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;ABC;NETCOREAPP2_0</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

This xml node is located directly in the root "Project"-node.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are building and publishing for different runtimes by passing different `--runtime` options (MSBuild property `RuntimeIdentifier`), you can condition on that property in the csproj file (allowing you to use `#if BUILT_FOR_WINDOWS` in your C# code):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'win-x64'">$(DefineConstants);BUILT_FOR_WINDOWS</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However you can also test the current OS at run time using:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
…

if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    // call windows function here
}
else
{
    // do something else here
}
```

As long as a function marked with `[DllImport(…)]` is not called on an OS where the library / method cannot be found, there shouldn't be any problems. Do note that `DllImport()` can also probe for different libraries depending on the os - so `DllImport("foo")` would check for `foo.dll`, `foo.dylib`, `libfoo.so` etc.

Comment: When you copy this answer, make sure you don't need `win10-x64` instead of `win-x64`. The latter refers to the portable dotnet runtime.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#windows-rids

Comment: perhaps you have a complete code example ? I can't make it work. There's no #if RID available. And if I define them it's not clear how to set a value there. In case of #if NET 6 and so on all is clear but it does not in case of RIDs

Answer (score 2):

Adding to a Martin Ullrich's answer: if you want to define constants based on `RuntimeIdentifier` in a referenced library project as opposed to a project with application entry point make sure that you include the list of identifiers which you use in a `RuntimeIdentifiers` property in the project's .csproj file, for example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64;linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you don't do it then the constants will not be defined as `RuntimeIdentifier` property will not be passed to the csproj, as was in my case.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2678#issuecomment-498967871

Comment: When building (without publishing) a NET 6 cross-platform console app, there is no RuntimeIdentifier set. I can start and debug the application from VS 2022 choosing Windows or WSL/Ubuntu as target, but I did not find any possibility to define BUILT_FOR_WINDOWS or BUILT_FOR_LINUX to be used in the C# code