# Operating system specific code in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

How can I write OS specific code in net core? Like golangs `<pkgname>_<osname>.go` files.

I tried to solve this problem with `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform` and `if/else` blocks, but I don't like it.

Comment: What do you mean by `OS specific code`, the point of `dot net core` is too be cross-platform so you don't have to code for specific operating system.

Comment: For example: I want to port this `https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil` library for .net core.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dot net core build platform/os specific code or class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557327/dot-net-core-build-platform-os-specific-code-or-class-files)

Comment: @RyanWilson I think `OS specific code` is quite clear: you want to code something for one specific OS.

An example could be writing to the system event log, which is only available on Windows. `EventLog.WriteEvent()` does not compile unless you tell the compiler to only compile that block of code for Windows or change the target to only compile for Windows.